# Read.table can't get all data lines

Tags: r

There is a strange thing when i use read.table to get data.

```
data=read.table('/home/tiger/nasdaqlisted.txt',head=T,sep='|')
dim(data)
[1] 750   6
```

in fact,there are 2454 lines in the file,what's wrong?
http://freeuploadfiles.com/bb3cwypih2d2

Comment: This is usually because of special characters or something of the sort. Is there anything funny about line 751 in the source file?

Comment: Please paste the first few lines of your text file in your question, so we can see what your data looks like.

Comment: Strangely enough, `read.delim("path/to/file", sep="|")` reads in all the lines for me. Can you try that and let me know if it works for you too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue comes from the fact that some of the names contain the quote character `'` (in names such as `Angie's List, Inc.`).
The default argument in `read.table` for `quote` being `"\"'"` it needs to be changed for your data to be read correctly.

```
read.table("path/to/file", header=TRUE, sep="|", quote="")
```

As per @mrdwab suggestion, `read.delim` having `"\""` as default `quote` argument will work without needing any change:

```
read.delim("path/to/file", header=TRUE, sep="|")
```

Comment: why don't you add in the `read.delim` explanation too along with the `quote` defaults as another alternative to make this answer more complete.